# Marquee horizontal text scroll with a fading effect?

Tags: javascript, scroll, marquee

I am looking for a solution for a single line Marquee horizontal text scroll with a fading effect using javascript (jquery if possible). Like a carousel text scroll. All the google searches gave me scrolling effects but with no fading effect.

I know that this can be done in flash but im avoiding it if there are other solutions.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you can do this is by creating a marquee and floating a semi-transparent image at its edge:

Any of the ones you found are fine, or use this one built in jQuery: http://remysharp.com/demo/marquee.html

Here's a fading image: http://www.collylogic.com/scripts/fade.png

Here's [the source where you can see actually SEE the fading effect](http://colly.com/scripts/scroll_fade.html) on the above image

The advantages of doing it this way is that you're not doing any expensive processing in javascript. You also have a wider variety of scrolling to choose from without having to worry about when or where to fade.

The disadvantage is that semi-transparent pngs need a hack to work in IE6. But since it's just eye candy, I'd imagine those few IE6 users won't be impacted that much.

Answer (score 3):

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
    #marquee{
        position: absolute;
    }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        function marqueePlay(){
            $("#marquee").animate(
                {
                left: $(window).width() - $("#marquee").width(),
                opacity: 0
                }, 10000, function(){
                    $("#marquee").css("left", 0);
                    $("#marquee").css("opacity", 1);
                    marqueePlay();
                }
            );
        }
        marqueePlay();
    }); 
</script>  
</head>
<body>
<div id="marquee">Weee...Weee...Duh!</div>
</body>
</html>
```